# Why is lookDev mode not working in blender 2.9

Tags: rendering

Good day, I recently upgraded to blender 2.9 and my lookdev mode (material preview mode) is not rendering at all. I can see how my materials look in render view mode but in lookdev my materials just appear grey like in the picture I attached.
This is my lookDev view (material preview)

[image: 1]

Here is my render view perfectly working

[image: 2]

I did some research and found that I am not  the only one facing the issue. I even upgraded my blender version (it was suggested as a possible solution) but that didn't solve the problem. I am using an HP laptop. May anyone please help me with my predicament.
Thanks in advance

Comment: This looks similar to a relatively common issue users began having around February or so where an update to the Adrenalin Drivers for AMD GPU's caused this behavior in blender 2.8 and above . The solution is generally to roll back your drivers to an older version, but before doing that, try enabling "High Quality Normals" under `Render Properties > Performance` first, and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Rather than take photos of your monitor post actual screenshots instead. See [How to take a screenshot](https://www.take-a-screenshot.org) So we don't have to guess if we are looking at a physical issues like reflections or smudges, a hardware issue such as a malfunctioning display, a software level bug or driver, or an or actual artifact or issue with the model itself.

Comment: Hi, I am using blender 2.93 and so I don't have the option to enable "High Quality Normals". Is it perhaps hidden in another tab. Thanks for the information on taking screenshot instead of photos. I apologise for my ignorance, I'm new here and still learning the ropes.

Comment: My apologies, I didn't look closely enough at the screenshots to see you're using Cycles - "High Quality Normals" is only available with the EEVEE render engine (Which LookDev uses a version of). This is why you can't find the option. Switch to eevee, change it (so you can see in lookdev) and then switch back to Cycles. - https://ibb.co/VqdMvY2

Comment: Thank you so much. That actually helped. I can now view my materials in lookDev. Thanks a lot again. This issue really got me thinking.